# Trying to compare a variable that is multiline in a if comparison

Tags: linux, bash, ksh

Here is the current file I am running:

```
#!/bin/ksh -x

export BIN_DIR="../../env"
. $BIN_DIR/vdenv.ksh

success="DROP
CREATE TABLE
GRANT"

$worker_dir/runsql.ksh ddl X X > chnl_avt_v1.log
result=$(sed -e '/DROP/,/GRANT/!d' chnl_avt_v1.log)

if [ "$result" -eq "success" ]; then
       echo "hi"
else 
       echo "NOO"
fi
```

Below is the error I receive even though I know that both $success and $result are the same. 
    result=DROP
    CREATE TABLE
    GRANT
    + [ DROP
    CREATE TABLE
    GRANT -eq success ]
    master_list_ddl.ksh[13]: DROP ^JCREATE TABLE^JGRANT: syntax error
    + echo NOO
    NOO

Comment: the error is not because of variable with multiple line it is because of other error

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in accessing the variable `success` and the wrong comparison operator:

```
if [ "$result" -eq "success" ]; then
```

obviously must be

```
if [ "$result" = "$success" ]; then
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ksh` (like `bash`) use `==` for string comparisons?

Comment: @steeldriver Funny I didn't notice that. That has happened to me before in the last days. It seems to be the case that when I have noticed an error that I stop searching on the same line...

Comment: @steeldriver, the standard operator is `=`. `ksh` also supports `==`, but there's no reason to use it.

Comment: OK thanks @StephaneChazelas - I haven't used `ksh` in about 15yrs so I was going by the AT&T ksh man page - which describes the `=` form as obselete.